# IDispatch::Invoke pass pointer of typedef struct as argument

Tags: c, windows, winapi, com

I need call function **GetRect** whose argument is pointer of structure **EdmRect** which has no **GUID**:

```
typedef struct tagEdmRect {
    long mlLeft;
    long mlTop;
    long mlRight;
    long mlBottom;
} EdmRect;

[
  odl,
  uuid(60F6AEB0-7AEA-49F5-A4EF-DCBB1F2E6284),
  helpstring("IEdmState7 Interface"),
  dual,
  oleautomation
]
interface IEdmState7 : IEdmState6 {
    [id(0x0000000e), helpstring("GetRect")]
    HRESULT GetRect([out] EdmRect* poRect);
};
```

Please tell me how i can do it correct?

Now i can't do it because always received **E_INVALIDARG**.

First i tried use **VT_RECORD** as VARTYPE:

```
GUID LIBID_RecInf1Lib = { 0x5fa2c692, 0x8393, 0x4f31, { 0x9b, 0xdb, 0x05, 0xe6, 0xf8, 0x07, 0xd0, 0xd3 } };

ITypeLib* typeLib = nullptr;
hRes = LoadRegTypeLib(LIBID_RecInf1Lib, 5, 17, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &typeLib);
if (FAILED(hRes))
    _com_issue_error(hRes);

uint typeCount = typeLib->GetTypeInfoCount();
for (uint i = 0; i < typeCount; ++i)
{
    BSTR name;
    typeLib->GetDocumentation(i, &name, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (wcscmp(name, L"EdmRect") == 0)
    {    
        ITypeInfo* typeInfo = nullptr;
        hRes = typeLib->GetTypeInfo(i, &typeInfo);
        if (FAILED(hRes))
            _com_issue_error(hRes);

        IRecordInfo* erRecInfo = nullptr;
        hRes = GetRecordInfoFromTypeInfo(typeInfo, &erRecInfo);
        qDebug() << erRecInfo;
        if (FAILED(hRes))
            _com_issue_error(hRes);

        EdmRect rect = { 0 };

        VARIANTARG* v = new VARIANTARG[1];
        VariantInit(&v[0]);
        v[0].vt = VT_RECORD;
        v[0].pvRecord = &rect;
        v[0].pRecInfo = erRecInfo;

        DISPPARAMS i_params = {v, NULL, 1, 0};

        auto func_id = dispIDofName("GetRect", disp); // This line correct
        hRes = disp->Invoke(func_id, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &i_params, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (FAILED(hRes))
            _com_issue_error(hRes);

        break;
    }
}
```

But function **GetRecordInfoFromTypeInfo** return **E_INVALIDARG**

Also i tried use **VT_PTR** and **VT_PTR | VT_BYREF** and **VT_USERDEFINED** and set pointer to VARIANT::byref, isn't worked.

Please help.

Comment: EdmRect is not a VARIANT, it's not an Automation type, you can't call it using IDispatch. Call it like a standard C function (you'll need a pointer to an IEdmState7 instance, not IDispatch)

Comment: @SimonMourier, are you sure? I have functions which have same arguments  

**HRESULT GetArrowVertices([out] SAFEARRAY(EdmPoint)* ppoVertices);**  

and EdmPoint is not "Automation type", but i can use this function using IDispatch. But EdmPoint have GUID. I'm using MinGW.

Comment: If the structure has no `GUID` associated with it, it's not an automation type. The structure that does have a `GUID`, may be used in automation if it meets other requirements (its members must themselves be automation-compatible). Whoever designed that interface probably never once tested it with late binding, or with marshaling involved.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , this functions and structure work fine in c# and visual c++ with #import derictive. But i don't know how use it in plain c++.

Comment: It should work if you don't use `IDispatch::Invoke`, but query for `IEdmState7` and call `GetRect` directly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , mingw has not directive #import :'(

Comment: You don't strictly need one (though it's very convenient). You may have header files that came with the IDL - just `#include` those. If you don't have them, run MIDL compiler on the IDL file, it generates a header as one of its outputs.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , I didn't know i could do that.
Thanks, i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDispatch only supports Automation compatible types. The list more or less described here:

[2.2.29.1 _wireVARIANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237870.aspx)

So, there are I8, I4, I2, I1, INT, UI8, UI4, UI2, UI1, UINT, R8, R4, CY, ERROR, BOOL, DECIMAL, NULL, EMPTY, DATE, BSTR, UNKNOWN, DISPATCH, BYREFs and SAFEARRAYs of all these, and RECORD (which was the latest addition historically).

That's it. No raw C structure, no VT_PTR, etc.

Other VT_* are reserved for PROPVARIANT which is a similar, but quite different beast, not supported by IDispatch (it works for blittable-compatible types).

So you *can* use a C structure, but it *must* be properly defined in type library (or/and in registry). If it's defined, you can call it an [Automation UDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221453.aspx) (user defined type).

> To pass single UDTs or safearrays of UDTs through type-library driven
>   marshaling for v-table binding, C and C++ Automation clients need the
>   header file generated from the IDL that describes the UDT
>
> Visual Basic clients require the type library generated from the IDL
>   file. However to pass single UDTs or safearrays of UDTs for late
>   binding, the Automation client must have the information necessary to
>   store the type information of the UDT into a VARIANT (and if
>   late-binding, the UDT must be self-described).

This is how you describe [UDT within .IDL files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221009.aspx)

```
library udttest
{
    typedef [uuid(C1D3A8C0-A4AA-11D0-819C-00A0C90FFFC3)]
    struct_tagUDT
    {
        unsigned long a1;
        BSTR pbstr;
    } UDT;
}
```

Since EdmRect is *not* a UDT (well, it appears it's not, but I don't have the original tlb at hand to confirm), you can only call it using early-binding, something like that:

```
IEdmState7 *pState;
disp->QueryInterface(IID_IIEdmState7, (void**)&pState);
EdmRect rect;
pState->GetRect(&rect);
...
```

So you need a .H header file for IEdmState7. If the vendor does not provide one (IMHO, he *should*, or the source .IDL), but you have a TLB, then all hope is not lost.

One solution is to use Visual Studio [#import directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) (there's the community edition that everyone can use), keep the .TLH and .TLI generated files and adapt them to your compiler (in this case, I suggest you use [raw_interfaces_only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ds25e53.aspx)).

Another solution is to use [OLE/COM Object Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx) (run as admin...) or a tool called [OleWoo](http://www.benf.org/other/olewoo/) wich is a nice replacement for the older one.

It should create a .H file from the.TLB. Note you only need the interface that don't support IDispatch, you don't need the whole .H file, if IDispatch is convenient for you.

Comment: There's a templatized version of QueryInterface where you can literally say: `disp->QueryInterface(&pState)` and it will infer the IID and no cast to void** required.  Look at the declaration for `IUnknown` in `Unknwnbase.h`. Sorry for messing up the edit the first time.

Comment: @selbie - yes, I know all that, but I didn't wanted to burden the message, keeping my code truly independent. There's also IID_PPV_ARGS, smart pointers, etc.